# disable commandLink when default checkbox is checked

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable in which first colm is delete and last colm is default checkbox,
I want to disable the delete commandlink when default is checked

```
<p:dataTable value="#{itemRelationshipBean.selectedItemsList}" var="selectedItem" styleClass="selected_item_table">
                <p:column styleClass="delete" headerText="#{msg['item.relationship.delete.column']}">
                    <h:commandLink styleClass="cross_icon">
                        <p:ajax immediate="true" event="click" update=":relationshipForm:selectedItemsPanel" 
                                listener="#{itemRelationshipBean.updateRelatedItemsList(true,selectedItem.itemId,selectedItem.itemName)}"
                                process="@this" onstart="loadingDialog.show();" 
                                oncomplete="loadingDialog.hide();addCSS();"/>                       
                    </h:commandLink>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Item Name">#{selectedItem.itemName}</p:column>
                <p:column styleClass="variants" headerText="#{msg['item.relationship.variants.column']}">
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectedItem.relationId}" style="width:80px; font-size:12px;" id="selectedCategoryId" styleClass="category">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{itemRelationshipBean.selRelationVariants}" var="relVariant" itemLabel="#{relVariant.relationForm}" 
                        itemValue="#{relVariant.relationId}" />
                        <f:ajax />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </p:column>
                <p:column styleClass="default" headerText="#{msg['item.relationship.is.default.column']}">

                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBoxDefault" value="#{selectedItem.defaultVal}"  onclick="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this);" disabled="true">
                    <f:ajax/>
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`p:commandLink`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandLink.jsf) instead, which provides a `disabled` attribute out of the box:

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="cross_icon" disabled="#{selectedItem.defaultVal}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you could use commandLink and selectBooleanCheckbox from Primefaces (as mentioned by Xtreme Biker).

I've noticed that your **selectBooleanCheckbox** is set to be disabled (**disabled="true"**). This will prevent model update for that component and the **selectedItem.defaultVal** value might never be changed.

You will probably need to revisit the **dataTableSelectOneRadio** function and make the proper modifications (note that onclick is not defined in Primefaces´s selectBooleanCheckbox component);

Here is my suggestion for your datatable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{itemRelationshipBean.selectedItemsList}" var="selectedItem" styleClass="selected_item_table">
    <p:column styleClass="delete" headerText="#{msg['item.relationship.delete.column']}">
        <p:commandLink id="deleteCl" styleClass="cross_icon" process="@this" immediate="true" update=":relationshipForm:selectedItemsPanel" 
                       actionListener="#{itemRelationshipBean.updateRelatedItemsList(true,selectedItem.itemId,selectedItem.itemName)}"
                       onstart="loadingDialog.show();" oncomplete="loadingDialog.hide();addCSS();" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Item Name">#{selectedItem.itemName}</p:column>
    <p:column styleClass="variants" headerText="#{msg['item.relationship.variants.column']}">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectedItem.relationId}" style="width:80px; font-size:12px;" id="selectedCategoryId" styleClass="category">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{itemRelationshipBean.selRelationVariants}" var="relVariant" itemLabel="#{relVariant.relationForm}" 
                           itemValue="#{relVariant.relationId}" />
            <f:ajax />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
    <p:column styleClass="default" headerText="#{msg['item.relationship.is.default.column']}">
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBoxDefault" value="#{selectedItem.defaultVal}">
            <p:ajax process="@this" update="deleteCl" />
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```